# Who was the slayer before Buffy?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

"When a slayer dies, a new slayer is chosen."

> When Buffy temporarily dies, Kendra is chosen as the new slayer.

Who was the slayer before Buffy?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[India Cohen](https://buffy.fandom.com/wiki/India_Cohen) was the slayer directly before Buffy.

She was killed by nomadic elemental mummies and sacrificed herself to save her watcher. She was briefly resurrected (by said watcher) in 1998 and sacrificed herself a second time to protect Buffy.

> *My name is India Cohen the Vampire Slayer. I was called in 1993, and I died in San Diego in 1996.*
>
> *I say again to her, “Who’s Buffy?*
>
> <sub><sup>[Buffy: The Book of Fours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_of_Fours)</sup></sub>

Comment: She died far too easily. Clearly not as buff.

Comment: Her spirit appeared in the book "Book Of Fours".